# How to serialize large number of objects with provided xsd schema?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xsd

I have large collection of objects that I need to transform into xml that must validate against given XSD.

Class structure is not very complex (aobut twenty properties and two lists of child classes) 
i.e:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Street, Town, City, PostCode etc;
   public double Income, Tax, etc.;
   public List<Account> Accounts;
   ...
}
```

but the expected xml output complex and does not match class structure

```
<Person>
  <Address>
    <Street/><Town/><City/>
  </Address>
  <FinancialData>
    <Income/><Tax/>
  </FinancialData>
  <Accounts>
  <Account>
    <No>1</No>
    ...
  </Accounts>
</Person>
```

What's the best way to do that?

I tried to make XElement structure for each object and then combine them into XDocument and save

```
XElement document = new XElement("Person",               
   new XElement("Address",
      new XElement("Street", this.Street),
      new XElement("City", this.City),
   new XElement("FinancialData",
      new XElement("Income", this.Income), ...
```

but process of creating XElements is very slow and with 200 objects it takes couple minutes wheras I need to serialize 50.000 objects.

I thought about XmlSerializer but class and xsd don't match.

UPDATE:
I created custom classes that I map my base class to it. Then using XmlSerializer and its attributes I serialize my objects in xml. It's pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this XDocument (Linq2Xml) would be simple but...

How about an old DataSet?
There are 2 ways:

1. Generate in Visual Studio:

   - Add xsd to C# project.
   - Open the file from Solution Explorer "Open with", select DataSet Editor..yes yes...
   - Click the DataSet and go to properties
   - Set name to [your_class] and set Custom Tool to MSDataSetGenerator
   - Now, VS will generate the code behind. Then you can use the generated class in the code.
2. Or, From Start menu -> Visual Studio -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Commend Prompt 
   has XSD.EXE which can be used to generate the class.

---

If you want to use XmlSerializer you can make an XslCompiledTransform to convert an xml document from one format to another with xsl stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to consider using a template engine of your choice, for example [NHaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/). First you have to create an XML template which conforms to your schema, then you use a template engine to render the template using your actual data.

In the case of NHaml it will look approximately like this:

```
%Person
  %Address
     %Street = person.Street
     %Town = person.Town
     %City = person.City
  ...
  %FinancialData
  - foreach (var account in person.Accounts)
    %Account
      %No
        = account.No
      ...
```